# Magento displays error after adding a product in the backend

Tags: magento, magento2, php-7

I am running a Linux Server with `Ubuntu 16.04` and `PHP 7.0.15` with `Magento 2.1.5`.

When I go into the backend Products -> Add Product and add a product without any special settings the Website breaks in the frontend and displays the following error:

```
We're sorry, an error occured while generating this email.
```

[image]

After checking the log files of magento I found these errors:

system.log

```
[2017-03-29 12:05:38] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1 and handles catalog_product_prices: Please correct the XML data and try again.
```

debug.log

```
[2017-03-29 12:37:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate: {"method":"GET","url":"http://MYSHOPURL/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

Any ideas what might cause this issue? Adding a product to a webshop software shouldn't break it ^^

If you need further information or any other logs please let me know! I will provide them as soon as possible.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding product from admin, run following command from CLI.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I already got it to work though the Theme support. But if thats what they did, I hope I don't encounter this problem everytime we add a new product.